# Why does notificatio not work on all devices?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

ich bin Neuling was das Programmieren angeht. Aktuell versuche ich, alles durch Tutorials etc zu lernen. Nun arbeite ich schon eine ganze weile an einem Problem...

Ich möchte den Besitzern meiner App "Push-Benachrichtigungen" senden. Nach viel hin und her hab ichs hingekriegt. An meinem PC hängt ein altes Samsung S6. Ich sende per Firebase eine Benachrichtigung, und diese poppt auch sofort auf. Nun habe ich die APK der App auf meinem Haupthandy installiert (Huawei Mate 20), dort kommt nichts an. Auch auf weiteren Handys nichts. Das einzige Handy, welches die Push-Nachrichten bekommt ist das S6 - WIESO?

Woran liegt das???

Google Translate:

I'm new to programming. Currently I try to learn everything through tutorials etc. Now I'm working on a problem for a while ...

I'd like to send the owners of my app "push notifications." After much back and forth I got it. On my PC hangs an old Samsung S6. I send a notification via Firebase, and it pops up immediately. Now I have the APK of the app installed on my main handset (Huawei Mate 20), it does not matter. Also on other mobile phones nothing. The only mobile phone that gets the push messages is the S6 - WHY?

Why is that ???

Comment: what Android versions are running on the different devices?

Comment: Huawei: 8.1, Samsung: 7.0

Comment: Now i wrote the app complet new, when i send a "testnotification" with firebase, then it pops up on the huawei, but after that, i send it regular, nothing happend...